# how do we do a command that makes it so we lose hunger faster in minecraft forever

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition, ios

I can’t really find the command for it. I need an example of what to do for the command and this thing is really making me angry. I searched all over the web for the command and I even searched on YouTube!

Answer (score 1):

Run a command block which grants you the Hunger effect for 60 seconds, and put it on a timer that repeats every 50 seconds.

The command would be `/effect @a minecraft:hunger 60 1 true`; the timer could be redstone or command block based. To make sure it is a constantly loaded chunk, `/forceload` it [(syntax here)](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/forceload).